# Random Triangle Artifacts on Screen

Tags: windows, display, nvidia-graphics-card

Need some help with strange problem. I have the following machine.

```
OS NameMicrosoft Windows 7 Enterprise   
Version6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601  
System Typex64-based PC  
ProcessorIntel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz, 2401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)  
ProcessorIntel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz, 2401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)  
BIOS Version/DateAmerican Megatrends Inc. 1.1, 3/26/2010  

Installed Physical Memory (RAM)16.0 GB  
Total Physical Memory16.0 GB  
Available Physical Memory12.4 GB  
Total Virtual Memory32.0 GB  
Available Virtual Memory27.3 GB  
Page File Space16.0 GB  

NameNVIDIA GeForce GTX 480  
Adapter TypeGeForce GTX 480, NVIDIA compatible  
Adapter DescriptionNVIDIA GeForce GTX 480  
Adapter RAM1.50 GB (1,610,285,056 bytes)  
Installed Driversnvd3dumx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvd3dum,nvwgf2um,nvwgf2um  
Driver Version8.17.13.142  
Resolution1920 x 1200 x 59 hertz  
Bits/Pixel32
```

I have been using this system without any problem for the last one year. But recently I started noticing a few different colored triangles whenever I used to for to some site with flash. But they were rare. Then one fine morning I noticed there were very frequent. Now whenever I play some video in VLC or youtube there are many triangles that appear. Then I noticed that the nvidia symbol inside the 3d settings which rotates it also has many triangles. I tried to take pictures of the triangles but the pictures dont show the extent of the problem.

But then I noticed that any software that uses 3d acceleration of the the hardware has many of these triangles. Attached are two images one with nvidia panel having some issues, second is a software utility GPU Caps Utility that has some fury 3d cube rotating and that shows many triangles in and around the video.

Also I have used the GPU Caps Utility before many times and it never used to show any triangles and it used to run fine.

Please let me know if somebody needs some other information to help me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was done straight after a driver update, I would blame that. However, if this happened out of the blue... Unfortunately, this is just random errors that occur when the graphics chip is on its way out, but not completely failed.

I had something similar on a laptop ages ago - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ae5nJbx1N38

A solution, but not a good one is to uninstall your drivers and use generic VGA graphics - this can sometimes help and get longer out of a machine that only has embedded graphics (such as a laptop).

...but in your case, as it is a workstation (heh, nice cpu(s)! :) ), I would say just buy a new one as it will fail before too long and my advice above will only get you a little longer out of it).

Comment: :( cuz my card needs replacement .. :) cuz I need to go shopping for a new card yaayyyy ...